# xbindkeys XF86Back sent twice

Tags: keyboard, mouse

I have configured my 10-button mouse as follows in xRDP for use with a Hyper-V enhanced session:

```
Option "Buttons" "10"
Option "ButtonMap" "1 2 3 4 5 8 9"

"xbindkeys -xsendevent -text "\[XF86Back]""
b: 6

"xbindkeys -xsendevent -text "\[XF86Forward]""
b: 7
```

This works for the first 7 buttons (standard 3 + 4-axis scroll). However when checking xev, I see that my mapping for buttons 6 and 7 are triggered twice per click. When I exit xbindkeys, the XF86Back event is never sent. Chrome does not respond to buttons 6 and 7 unless I map to XF86Back/Forward. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to eliminate the extra keypress?

Answer (score 0):

This one will remain unsolved. Closer examination of xev showed that both buttons 6 and 7 and buttons 8 and 9 return a button press of 6 and 7 respectively. Button 8 and Button 9 codes are not sent at all. This is a Logitech Ergo trackball, so maybe the Windows driver has something to do with that (running through Hyper-V manager via enhanced session/xrdp). In any case, it is not possible to distinguish between the two sets of buttons.

I've removed the ButtonMap and disabled buttons 8-10. This way I still get 4-axis scroll, but I use the keyboard for forward/back. Too bad, I'd gotten used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for this issue.
It's not pretty, but it works reliable enough for me.

The .xbindkeysrc configuration allows to specify arbitrary commands.
By using temporary files that are stored in the home directory of the user the current state of the button press can be saved and retrieved when the second press occurs.
With that the second press is then ignored and the temporary file deleted.

```
"if [ -f ~/.xbindkeys_back_pressed ]; then rm ~/.xbindkeys_back_pressed; else touch ~/.xbindkeys_back_pressed; xbindkeys -xsendevent -text '\[XF86Back]'; fi"
  b:6

"if [ -f ~/.xbindkeys_forward_pressed ]; then rm ~/.xbindkeys_forward_pressed; else touch ~/.xbindkeys_forward_pressed; xbindkeys -xsendevent -text '\[XF86Forward]'; fi"
  b:7
```

In my case the xbindkeys does not seem to support xsendevent, so I'm using xte instead.

```
"if [ -f ~/.xbindkeys_back_pressed ]; then rm ~/.xbindkeys_back_pressed; else touch ~/.xbindkeys_back_pressed; xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'keydown Left' 'keyup Left' 'keyup Alt_L'; fi"
  b:6

"if [ -f ~/.xbindkeys_forward_pressed ]; then rm ~/.xbindkeys_forward_pressed; else touch ~/.xbindkeys_forward_pressed; xte 'keydown Alt_L' 'keydown Right' 'keyup Right' 'keyup Alt_L'; fi"
  b:7
```